# Scala - how to read method signatures

Tags: scala, methods

I am new to Scala and trying to understand a following method:

```
def method1 = {
    val key = "k1"
    val value = "v1"
    basicSetup() { (a, b, c) =>
        val json = s"""{"field1":"$value"}"""
        someMethodTest.send(a, b, json, c)
    } { (record, avroObject, schema) =>
        if (avroObject.get("field1").toString != value) {
            failure("failed")
        } else {
            success
        }
    }
}
```

So far I worked on simple methods and understand when is a simple call and return but here it looks like is bundled stuff in it.

Need a help to understand how to read it from `basicSetup` line (just a general flow, signature and return).

e.g. Why is here 2 blocks of code: `basicSetup() { ... } { ...}` (how is it being executed?)

```
private def basicSetup()
   (run: (Producer, String, Schema) => Unit)
   (verify: (ProducerRecord[String, Array[Byte]], GenericRecord, Schema) => Result) = {

...
...

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to look at the definition of `basicSetup`, but it looks like a method with three parameter groups, the last two of which are themselves functions (making `basicSetup` a higher-order function).

The first parameter group is empty `()`.

The second and third are two "closures" or blocks of code or anonymous functions.

You could rewrite this as

```
// give names to these blocks
def doSomethingWithABC(a:A, b:B, c:C) = ???
def doSomethingWithAvro(record: R, avro: O, schema: S) = ???

basicSetup()(doSomethingWithABC)(doSomethingWithAvro)
```

> Why is here 2 blocks of code ?

This is syntactic sugar to make function calls (especially higher-order function calls) look more like "built-in" constructs. So you can roll your own control flow methods. Keyword here is DSL.

These two blocks are parameters to `basicSetup`. They can appear as just bare blocks (without any parameter parentheses) to make it more concise (and natural, once you get used to it).

---

Update (now that we have the signature):

```
private def basicSetup()
  (run: (Producer, String, Schema) => Unit)
  (verify: (ProducerRecord[String, Array[Byte]], GenericRecord, Schema) => Result) = {
```

Indeed. The function takes three parameter groups.

The first one is actually empty, so you just call it with `()`. But it could have some parameters, even optionals, maybe to add configuration.

The second one is your "callback" to "run" (after this basic setup has been completed). It itself is a function that will be called with three parameters, a `Producer`, a `String` and a `Schema`.

The third one is your code to "verify" the results of all that. It looks at three parameters and returns a `Result` (presumably indicating that all is good or what went wrong).

Comment: Thanks.. so what is a rule when calling a method with 3 parameter groups?  Do we need to provide 3 different paramater groups in each call? Or 1 is enough and the method that is being called will figure out which one to use?

Comment: These three are not either/or. You still need to specify all parameters. The groups are just a way to "group" them. In addition to facilitating concise syntax like above, groups can also be used to do "currying": You can provide one group at a time, giving you back a partially-applied function (that you could pass around and supply the other parameters later).

Comment: Thanks, but not following completely. What does it mean `partially-applied` function (in English) :)  Why would someone create a code like this? (to have 3 parameter groups)

Comment: Without the parameter groups, it would be more clumsy (syntax-wise) to call this function. You'd need more parentheses and comma between parameters.

Comment: "partially-applied" means that you can take a function like `add` which takes two numbers and provide it with just one parameter like `3` to get a new function that still takes another parameter and adds three to it. This could be useful to provide context that the final caller may not have access to. Like turning a function that needs a file handle into a function that does not (for example to make a callback for logging).